# Zend Mailer error "From header set twice"

Tags: email, zend-framework, zend-mail

My question in based on Zend Mail

I have a class that extends Zend Mail. Basically it is supposed to send two different mails to users upon registration.

It has two functions sendRegistrationMail and sendActivationMail and both methods use the same transport initiallized in constructor.

Calling the two functions sendRegistrationMail works but the second one gives the error: `**From Header Set Twice**`

```
class Mailer_Register_SendMail extends Zend_Mail
{

    public $_config;
    public $_transport;
    public $_email;
    public $_fromEmail;
    public $_fromFullName;


    public function __construct($email)
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->_config=array('auth'=>'login','ssl'=>'tls','username'=>"$email",'password'=>'12345678','port'=>'25');
        $this->_transport=new Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp('127.0.0.1',$this->_config);
        $this->_email=$email;
        $this->_fromEmail="administrator@rta.com";
        $this->_fromFullName="RTAsys.com";
    }



    public function sendRegistrationMail()

    {
        $emailmessage="<h3>Welcome to the Atanik Authorization</h3></br>".
                        "<p>You will soon receive your activation email as a separate message</p>";

                        $fromemail=$this->_fromEmail;
                        $fromfullname=$this->_fromFullName;
                        $to=$this->_email;
                        $subject="Welcome to RTA";

                        $this->setBodyHtml($emailmessage);
                        $this->setFrom($fromemail,$fromfullname);
                        $this->addTo($to);
                        $this->setSubject($subject);

                        try {
                        $this->send($this->_transport);

                        }
                        catch (Zend_Mail_Transport_Exception $ex)
                        {

                        }


    }

    public function sendActivationMail()
    {


                    $subjectActivation="Activate Your Angaza Account";

                    $emailActivationMessage="Thank you for taking time to join Atanik
                    Authorization Please click the link below to activate your account now
                    http://localhost/RTAsys/public/Account/activate?email=".$this->_email;


                    $fromActivationEmail=$this->_fromEmail;

                    $fromActivationFullName=$this->_fromFullName;

                    $to=$this->_email;


                    $this->setBodyText($emailActivationMessage);
                    $this->setFrom($fromActivationEmail,$fromActivationFullName);
                    $this->addTo($to);
                    $this->setSubject($subjectActivation);
                    try
                     {
                    $this->send($this->_transport);
                     }
                     catch (Zend_Mail_Transport_Exception $ex)
                     {

                     }          
    } 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `clearFrom()` to clear your headers during every iteration, if you really must use the same Zend_Mail object for a single iteration:

```
$mail = new Zend_Mail();
foreach ($users as $key => $user) {
    $mail->clearFrom();
    $mail->setFrom('foo@bar');
    // do some more stuff
}
```

The error itself is pretty self-explanatory: you are calling `setFrom()` more than once, which is not needed. Most likely this is being caused by having instantiated the `Zend_Mail` object outside of an iteration and calling `setFrom()` from within this iteration.

Comment: Obviously am not clear on your answer as am still learning, my class extends Zend_Mail. The first function is ok, i do stuff like $this->setfrom(),$this->setBody..and then i $this->send($transport) ..so do i clear all these after sending. My second function is almost similar. I appreciate

Comment: @jamon are you asking a question?

Comment: Rotteveel, i have attached my simple code as i kept getting errors even after clearFrom. Could you assist

Comment: @jamon, I don't see you calling clearFrom() anywhere. Read my answer again: it *will* solve the problem, if applied correctly.

Comment: @jamon just add $this->clearFrom(); at the end of sendRegistrationMail()